# Jump Search Algorithm in C

Tags: c, search

I am trying to implement the jump search algorithm, and I had a couple of questions. Here is my attempt of the algorithm:

```
#include "search_algos.h"

/**
 * jump_search - search for a value in an array using the
 * jump search algorithm
 * @array: the array to be searched
 * @size: size of the array to be searched
 * @value: value to be searched in the array
 *
 * Return: If the value is found in the array, it will return
 * the index of the first match it has found. Otherwise, it
 * returns -1, and errno is set appropriately.
 */
int jump_search(int *array, size_t size, int value)
{
        int val = sqrt(size), prev, step;

        if (!array)
                return (-1);

        prev = 0;
        step = val;
        while (step < (int)size && array[step] < value)
        {
                prev = step;
                step += val;
        }
        while (prev <= step && prev < (int)size)
        {
                if (array[prev] == value)
                        return prev;
                prev += 1;
        }
        return -1; 
}
```

I have seen implementations of the algorithm in the internet and I have seen that they use the `sqrt()` function which is alright, but they don't floor it and just go on with the implementation but wont that be accessing an illegal memory location?

My second question is that I have implemented it the algorithm in a way that once I have found an element greater than value to be searched I go back to the previous block and do a linear search in that block. But it is giving me some inconsistent results.

Comment: OT: Pushing multiple expressions or statement together as a single line using the comma operator can make the code harder to read, understand and maintain. Also note that the comma operator is an expression, with a result that you ignore. It likely won't affect the effectiveness of the generated code (at least not for the better). If you need to do multiple things, do them as multiple distinct statements instead.

Comment: Not yet digged deeper but: `while (array[prev] < value && prev < size)` – if `prev < size` is not met any more than you access the array out of bounds when doing `array[prev] < value` right before, which is undefined behaviour (unless the array actually is larger than `prev` in size and `size` variable simply contains a smaller value, forming a sub-array). You need to test in inverse order: `prev < size && array[prev] < value`!

Comment: For goodness sake, for the love of god, in the name of everything that you hold dear and sacred, compute `sqrt(size)` ***ONLY ONCE***.

Comment: `i <= (int)prev` – honestly, make `i` size_t as well. Additionally: Prefer keeping the scope of a loop variable local to the loop, such as: `for(size_t i = ...; i <= prev; ++i)`. On returning, you still can cast, though note that `int` actually cannot cover the full range of `size_t` – if you have an array larger than `INT_MAX` and the value to be looked up resides beyond `INT_MAX` you cannot return its index. Maybe unlikely, even unrealistic, but you should at least be aware of.

Comment: And don't place parentheses around return values – `return` is not a function. If you ever get to meet C++ there are even cases where this can badly go wrong (producing dangling references as in `decltype auto f() { int n = 7; return (n); }`)

Comment: @Aconcagua Okay, I will make all the changes you pointed out, thanks.

Comment: Just a recommendation: You might want to get used to *always* place the braces around if/else or loop bodies; many well known coding conventions, e.g. MISRA, even make that mandatory. This prevents you from ugly bugs like forgetting to place them on adding further expressions or worse, badly written macros that look like functions; consider: `#define looksLikeAFunction(X, Y) ++X; ++Y /*...*/ if(someCondition) looksLikeAFunction(a, b);` – can you imagine what goes wrong now? In given case it makes the multi-expression sequence obsolete as well (see @Someprogrammerdude 's comment).

Comment: About your actual questions: `floor` is obsolete when you convert a double to int (here_ by the assignment), the fractional part is cut away in this case anyway, so the effect is just the same (note: for negative values as well, so `-0.7` assigned to an `int` gets 0 just like `0.7` would).

Comment: Not sure what you mean about inconsistent results, you should be more precise. Which input did provoke which (incorrect) result? Are you aware that this algorithm only works on *sorted* arrays, by the way?

Comment: Your variable names are not really optimal, by the way. You are adding something to the beginning of a search range, what you add there is usually the *'step*' – that's what you, though, have named `val`... I personally would have preferred names like `start`, `begin` or alike (meant is the begin/start of the range you intend to look up) or you find something completely differently...

Comment: Just noticing: There's a substantial change in your code in your last edit, your original for-loop had `i = prev - val; i <= prev` – meaning you looked up the wrong range (or worse, *in front of the entire array*, thus UB, if you never incremented in the loop) before. That got fixed with your edit...

Comment: There's a problem with such edits, though: Answers or comments posted prior to these edits get invalidated this way. For this reason you should avoid such edits, or at least make them clearly visible (leaving old version, appending new version marked appropriately). Leave it for now, but keep in mind next time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, even if the square root value is not perfect and the value of the square root is not an integer, then also the algorithm will work correctly, but in the step increments the step value may go above the size of the array and it may miss the last elements of the array, but other than that the algorithm will always work.

And to answer your second question, the jump search algorithm has its pros and cons, and if you are going for the little extra speed of the algorithm and its easier implementation, you will have to deal with its memory safety issues, and due to this, you may have to do extra comparisons and this will slow down the program. Hence, if you need the speed and performance so badly, I would suggest going for the Binary Search algorithm.